# Изменить высоту QTableWidget, вставленного в QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyside2, qtablewidget

в item QTreeWidget с помощью setItemWIdget вставил таблицу QTableWidget. Вопрос в том, что вставленный виджет таблицы по умолчанию имеет слишком большую высоту, из-за чего строка item`а тоакже становится слишком высокой.
Смог уменьшить высоту через participation_table.setFixedHeight(), но тогда съедается и текст в других колонках.
Может ли QTableWidget иметь высоту по количеству собственных строк?[image: Большая высота]

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему, о которой вы пишите.